# Sum int values of an array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a `records` collection with thousands of documents, like the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee1e209e07f053f990cea8c"), "key" : "TAKwGc6Jr4i8Z487", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-28T01:22:14.398Z"), "counts" : [ 150, 160 ], "value" : "Doc1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee1e8dee07f053f990ceaa1"), "key" : "TAKwGc6Jr4i8Z487", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-28T01:22:14.398Z"), "counts" : [ 170 ], "value" : "Doc2" }
...
```

I want to write a query to select them by date range, and by the total count of elements in the `counts` array field.

I haven't managed to find any resources on that.
Should an aggregation be used, in this case?

Like `$sum` something?

```
{$and:[
  {createdAt:{$gte:ISODate('2016-01-30'),$lt:ISODate('2016-02-01')}},
  {<sum> ???}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a field to calculate sum of `counts` using `$addFields`, then use `$match` to compare sum and finally remove that temporary field before return using `$unset`.
Here is the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kVqTCSkAc21) for your example.

Comment: Please, how can I add the range date filter to your query?
Also, can I use $gt and $lte instead of $match ?

Comment: I've modified the playground link and added filter by date range for `createdAt`. You can use $gt and $lte in $match.